# is there a way to tell the VM budget for a device programmatically?

Tags: android, memory

is there a way programmatically to determine VM budget size?  I found lots of people commenting about exceeding it, but I was wondering if there was a way to determine it at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use  `Runtime.maxMemory()`.  Based on this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html) 
**Returns the maximum amount of memory that may be used by the virtual machine**